# DataTables create a column variable

Tags: javascript, datatables

I need to create a variable "name" which represents values in the Name column and use the variable in a hyperlink, generated in a subsequent column (ID).

```
var table1 = $("#table1").DataTable({
  "ajax": {
  "url": "www.qwe.com",
  "dataSrc": "info"
  },
  "columns": [
      { "data": "name",  "width": "45%"},
      { data : "id",
      "title": "ID",
      "width": "45%",
      "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
          return '<a href="www.123.com/info?name=' + name + ">' + data +   '</a>';}},       
      { "data": "value", "width": "10%" }]
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks generally OK. There is already a column ("data":"name") present.

I think you need row.name instead of name in your concatenation.

Comment: If you check the hyperlink in the render function, it contains a variable 'name', which is undefined. I want to define a variable 'name' which would be equal to the name value in the ("data":"name") column. Thanks @AntonioCiolino

Comment: my suggestion is to use row.name, which will take the value of "name" from the data row, and put it in your string that you are building for display in the "id" column.